# How to rename items on oracle rest api using ords

Tags: json, oracle, rest, api, oracle-ords

I want to change the name "items" on the json generate by ords on REST API.
I want to be the table name or dll instructions like "insert" or "update".

I have the ords installed and runnig.
On a module I have the GET: http://localhost:80/ords/db/products/:idTab

When I access the URL the JSON returned like this:

```
{

    "items": [
        {
            "id_prod": 18159,
            "desc_prod": "ABRAC. \"D\"   1\""
        }
}
```

I want to replace the items name to the table name (product).
How Can I do this on the ords ?

```
{

    "items": [
        {
            "id_prod": 18159,
            "desc_prod": "ABRAC. \"D\"   1\""
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.

Oracle has a REST standard, which dictates the JSON response format you see for a collection using that "items" structure.

If you want something else, you would need to create the the JSON yourself, and return the output as a media resource (clob or blob) with a mime type as application-json => when you do that, we don't convert the output to JSON.

[image]

[Example here.](https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2017/09/ords-returning-raw-json/)

Comment: You can also create a "Collection query item" and move your SQL into a single subquery named whatever you want. But you miss the benefits of automatic pagination, (but you can implement a bastardization with your own defined parameters and the "fetch only" clause